# input box not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, input, onclick

I am trying to have a basic filter when someone puts a word into a input box and list items hide on click, this is working fine in chrome but in firefox it is not working at all.

html:

```
<form ACTION="#" id="navsform" class="my-search">
<input id="formwidth" type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search...">
<input type="submit" class="my-button" value="Search" onclick="query_searchvar()"></form>
```

javascript:

```
function query_searchvar()
{
var searchquery=document.navsform.query.value.toLowerCase();
if(searchquery == '')
{alert("No Text Entered");
}
var queryarray = searchquery.split(/,|\s+/);

event.preventDefault();


$('li').each(function() {
  var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
  //alert(searchtags);
  var searcharray = searchtags.split(',');
//alert(searcharray);
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++)
    if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], queryarray)>-1) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

if (found == true )
  {

 $(this).show("normal");
  }
else {
$(this).hide("normal");
}
});
}
```

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Hi, I managed to get this working with a combo of all your comments and some jquery resources:
HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="#" class="my-search">
  <input id="formwidth" type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search..." />
  <input class="my-button"  type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>


$('#myform').submit(function() {
var searchquery = String($('#myform input[name=query]').val()).toLowerCase();
  if (searchquery == '') {
  alert('No Text Entered');
  }
var queryarray = searchquery.split(/,|\s+/);
$('li').each(function() {
  var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
  var searcharray = searchtags.split(',');
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < searcharray.length; i++)
    if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], queryarray) > -1) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

if (found == true) {

 $(this).show('normal');
  }
else {
$(this).hide('normal');
}

});
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you made a running example on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. document.navsform.query.value ???
2. onclick="query_searchvar()" ???
3. event.preventDefault ??? -- lack crossbrowser
4. Why Use click rather than submit?
5. missing return false?

why use it?

You're already using jQuery, it would be better to work 100% with Jquery?

```
<form ACTION="#" id="navsform" class="my-search">
<input id="formwidth" type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search...">
<input type="submit" class="my-button" value="Search"></form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#navsform").submit(function(event){
event = event||window.event; //Cross
var searchquery=String($("#navsform input[name=query]").val()).toLowerCase();
if(searchquery == ''){
alert("No Text Entered");
}
var queryarray = searchquery.split(/,|\s+/);

event.preventDefault();


$('li').each(function(){
var searchtags = $(this).attr('data-searchtags');
//alert(searchtags);
var searcharray = searchtags.split(',');
//alert(searcharray);
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<searcharray.length; i++){
if ($.inArray(searcharray[i], queryarray)>-1) {
    found = true;
    break;
}
}
if (found == true ){
$(this).show("normal");
} else {
$(this).hide("normal");
}
});
});
return false;//prevents sending the form, remove if necessary.
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm only starting out so its a mixture of what I could get working. Really appreciate your help. The code you listed doesn't work so maybe I need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Would like to post your entire code, so I will be able to make it work because it lacks the HTML, such as tags <LI>.

I wait.

Comment: Put in as jsFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) said epascarello so we can help you :D

Comment: Hi, okay so this is the basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/4a76e/6/ . But it doesn't seem to work on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things, you should change:

1. Pass in the event object to the handler function.
2. Attach the eventhandler to the form submit event, not the button. This way the return key will work.
3. Then you should use a tool like Firebug, Dragonfly or similar. It helps a lot. As mentioned in the comments, you could have found your error.

See Guilherme Nascimento's answer for an example. (But ignore the tone..)